# Spring Data+JPA: enforce inner join for OneToOne relationship

Tags: postgresql, jpa, spring-data, inner-join, querydsl

I have an Entity with OneToOne relation, which is used just to sort results:

```
@Entity
public class Document {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @OneToOne()
    SortProperty sortProp;

    ...

}
```

Then I have repository (using QueryDSL predicates):

```
public interface DocumentRepository 
             implements PagingAndSortingRepository<Document, Long>,
                        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Document> {

     @EntityGraph(value = "Document.forceJoins")
     Page<Document> findAll(Predicate queryDslPredicate, Pageable pageable); 

     ...
}
```

As you see above, I use `@EntityGraph` to control joining relations in the main query. All this work well, the only problem is performance - `@OneToOne` is fetched vith `left outer join` which means that DB index is not used:

```
    select * from
       document document0_ 
    left outer join
       sortproperty sortproper3_ 
        on document0_.documentid=sortproper3_.documentid 
     ...
```

Is there any way how to enforce using `inner join` instead of `left outer join`?

I have tried several things - `@OneToOne(optional = false)`, `@org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch`, but no success ... Parts generated from QueryDSL predicate(s) use properly inner joins for the property, but the main part of query use always `left outer join`. I was trying also use annotation with this method:

`@Query("select doc from Document doc inner join doc.sortProperties props")`

but I was unable to use it properly together with paging and QueryDSL predicates.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `@Query` annotation.

```
@Query("select doc from Document doc join doc.sortProp props")
```